# Symfony 4 - redirect user after login is no active

Tags: symfony

I use Symfony 4.1, and I want to redirect the user to login page if he is not active (field in my DB).

So I created a customer UserChecker :

```
class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * UserChecker constructor.
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return bool|void
     */
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (! $user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        // user is not active
        if ($user->getActive() == 0) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login'));
            //throw new AccessDeniedHttpException("Account not active");
        }
    }
    ....
```

But, my user is not redirected, the Exception works but I only want to redirect him with a custom message (I will use Flash Session).

How can I do that ? The Symfony docs only provide Exception messages, but it's not enought flexible for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my UserChecker I have these two checks:

```
    if ($user->isAccountLocked($maxMinutesLocked)) {
        $ex = new LockedException('User account is locked.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }

    if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
        $ex = new DisabledException();
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }
```

So, I guess your `$user->getActive() == 0` will be the same than my `!$user->isEnabled()`.

I think you just need to throw the `DisabledException` and you will arrive to the login page once again.

I hope will be useful this answer, I'm not actually a specialist in this subject.

Comment: Ah yes very nice ! This Exception makes the thing ! Thanks !